# create a drop down on a php webpage

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I wanted to create static and a dynamic drop down for an online application form on my web page

The static drop down would a list of clearance levels where the dynamic one would be based on a list of job openings (which is in turn taken from a folder that has 1 pdf file for each job opening)

the end goal is that an email would be sent to our hr director with the applicants info. and the fields in the body of the email.

I'm fairly new to php so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Code please??? something that your working on

Comment: I got nothing im not even sure how to make them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="education">
    <option value="Jr.High">Jr.High</option>
    <option value="HighSchool">HighSchool</option>
    <option value="College">College</option>
</select>
```